# Web scraping with splashr fails with curl error after many successes

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, splash-js-render

I am scraping a few dozen URLs using splashr which uses Splash in a Docker container as documented [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splashr/vignettes/intro_to_splashr.html).

The code runs and completes fine when run directly from RStudio Server on my Digital Ocean Droplet. However, when it runs from a cron job it always fails when reading the 24th URL with this error:

`Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :  Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Even when it works through running the code direct from RStudio I see this error the first 14 scrapes:

`QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::error: Internal problem, this method must only be called once.`

But it completes OK.

Is there some memory management or garbage collection that I'm supposed to be doing between scrapes? What would account for the success of a direct run and the failure of the same script being run by a cron job? In short, how do I avoid the curl error mentioned above?

```
library("tidyverse")
library("splashr")
library("rvest")

# Launch SplashR
# system2("docker", args = c("pull scrapinghub/splash:latest"))
# system2("docker", args = c("run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 scrapinghub/splash:latest"), wait = FALSE)
# splash_active()

pause_after_html_read <- 5
pause_after_html_text <- 3

for(idx in 1:28){  
  
  splash(host = "localhost", port = 8050L) |> 
    splash_response_body(FALSE) %>%
    splash_go(url = url_df$web_page[idx]) %>%
    splash_wait(pause_after_html_read) %>%
    splash_html() |> 
    html_text() -> pg
  
    Sys.sleep(pause_after_html_text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading this [post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/08/in-brief-splashr-update-high-performance-scraping-with-splashr-furrr-teamhg-memexs-aquarium/) told me about [Aquarium](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/aquarium). It uses a little bit more memory than before but doesn't crash.